# How to get user name in Microsoft bot framework in C# using V4?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to get **userName** in chatbot application using latest bot version v4. 
How to get **username** in updated bot version v4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/*In latest bot version v4, you can get userName using following code*/

public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
var userName = turnContext.Activity.From.Name;
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Welcome - {userName }");
}
```

Comment: Additionally, the MS Bot Framework has a v4 samples repo, one of which is a sample on how to get and display a user name (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/03.welcome-users)